# why "application:get_key(x,x)" not work?

Tags: erlang

I try to get vsn information for printing. But the return value is [].

The app file is following:

```
{application,john,
             [{description,[]},
              {vsn,"0.1.2.3"},
              {registered,[john]},
              {applications,[kernel,stdlib]},
              {mod,{john_app,[]}},
              {env,[]},
              {modules,[john_app,john_basic_rule,john_basic_sup,john_client,
                        john_cookie,john_env,john_file,john_framing_0_0_1,
                        john_framing_tests,john_group_sup,john_guid,john_ldap,
                        john_ldap_tests,john_local_message,john_log,
                        john_log_tests,john_message,john_mnesia,john_model,
                        john_rabbitmq,john_reader,john_reader_2_sup,
                        john_reader_sup,john_reader_tests,john_reader_tests_2,
                        john_store,john_store_tests,john_sup,john_upgrade,
                        john_version,john_worker,john_worker_tests]}]}.
```

The xxx_app.erl file is as follows:

```
start(normal, []) ->
    lager:md(?OP_ST),
    lager:debug("john_app_start_1"),
    case erts_version_check() of
        ok ->
            lager:debug("john_start_2"),
            try
                %% 是否需要启动john_sup依赖的服务器??
                true = register(john, self()),
                [ok = run_boot_step(Step) || Step <- boot_steps()],
                {ok,Sup_pid} = john_basic_sup:start_link(),
                ok = john_basic_sup:start_basic(),
                print_banner(),
                {ok, Sup_pid}
            catch Error_a:Reason_a->
                    lager:error("john_app_start_normal_3:~p,~p,~n~p",
                                [Error_a,Reason_a,erlang:get_stacktrace()]),
                    Reason_a                        
            end;
        Error ->
            lager:error("john_start_error:~p",[Error]),
            Error
    end.

print_banner() ->
    {ok, Product} = application:get_key(john,id),
    {ok, Version} = application:get_key(john,vsn),
    ProductLen = string:len(Product),
    lager:info("~n"
              "john--------------~n"
              "~s~n~s~n~s~n~s~n~s~n",
              [Product, string:right([$v|Version], ProductLen),
               ?PROTOCOL_VERSION,
               ?COPYRIGHT_MESSAGE, ?INFORMATION_MESSAGE]),
```

Then I tried application:get_all_key(), and it returns [].

Why?

I have tried `application:loaded_applications()` and `application:get_all_keys()`. But the result is not expected:

```
(zarah_john_slave_21@yus-iMac.local)3> application:loaded_applications().
[{goldrush,[],"0.1.0"},
 {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.16.2"},
 {lager,"Erlang logging framework","2.0.0"},
 {friar,[],"0.1.2"},
 {amqp_client,"RabbitMQ AMQP Client","2.8.2"},
 {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.9"},
 {inets,"INETS  CXC 138 49","5.9.5"},
 {john,[],"0.1.2.3"},
 {jotham,"pgsql jacob install","0.1.1"},
 {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.3.2"},
 {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.19.2"}]
(zarah_john_slave_21@yus-iMac.local)4> application:get_all_key().
[]
(zarah_john_slave_21@yus-iMac.local)5>
```

I have tried application:get_all_key(john).

```
{ok,[{description,[]},
     {id,[]},
     {vsn,"0.1.2.3"},
     {modules,[john_app,john_basic_rule,john_basic_sup,
               john_client,john_cookie,john_env,john_file,
               john_framing_0_0_1,john_framing_tests,john_group_sup,
               john_guid,john_ldap,john_ldap_tests,john_local_message,
               john_log,john_log_tests,john_message,john_mnesia,john_model,
               john_rabbitmq,john_reader|...]},
     {maxP,infinity},
     {maxT,infinity},
     {registered,[john]},
     {included_applications,[]},
     {applications,[kernel,stdlib]},
     {env,[{db_host,"xxx.xxx.com"},
           {db_port,5432},
           {ldap_options,[{timeout,7000},{anon_auth,true}]},
           {mq_username,<<"john_2">>},
           {link_exchange,<<"exchange_john_2">>},
           {included_applications,[]},
           {ldap_password,"helloworld"},
           {ldap_user,"admin"},
           {mq_port,5672},
           {db_password,<<"xxxx">>},
           {is_direct_link,false},
           {db_database,"db_jotham"},
           {cluster_nodes,[...]},
           {mq_address,...},
           {...}|...]},
     {mod,{john_app,[]}},
     {start_phases,undefined}]}
```

In addition, when get_key function is available?
    {ok, Product} = application:get_key(john,id),
    {ok, Version} = application:get_key(john,vsn),

In the above `start(normal,[])`, `get_key` function is not available, but after server is finished starting up, `get_key(john,vsn)` is available. I am still trying to find why.

The problem has been solved, it is related to 'copy-and-no-think'. The code is originally from rabbitmq's `rabbit.erl` file.

The following code caused the problem:

```
 [Product, string:right([$v|Version], ProductLen),
```

rabbitmq's "ProductLen" key is not 0. But my ProductLen is 0,string:right(xxx,0) return "". So the problem appeared.

Thank you for your clues for debugging.

Comment: Does your application start properly? Because it looks like application specification was not loaded which could indicate that *.app file was not found.

Comment: Have you defined the environment variables `id` and `vsn` anywhere? They are not set in the `.app` file which is the usual place for default values. They can also be defined in a config file or on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The application resource file should be called Application.app where Application is the name of the application. The file should be located in the ebin directory for the application.

First, check the `app` file name is `john.app`?

Second, check the `app` file is in right directory?

you can use `loaded_applications() -> [{Application, Description, Vsn}]` to check if your application loaded successfully.

Comment: I have pasted the result in the above.